# Placement of items in flexbox isn´t same

Tags: html, css, position, flexbox

Why is second row of images moved differently than the first one?

This is how markup and CSS look like

```
<div class="hook">
        <div><img class="nahledy" src="fotky/masaze-iren.jpg"></div>
        <div class="popis" style="display: none;">
        <h3 class="zrus H3Left">Web pro masáže</h3>
        <a class="OdkazReference" href="http://www.masaze-iren.cz" target="_blanc">www.masaze-iren.cz</a>
        <p><b>Zadání práce:</b><br>Nový web nahradil původní web zákazníka, který byl již velice zastaralý. Cílem bylo vytvořit přehledný web s nabídkou služeb, dobře dohledatelný přes Google a Seznam. Respozivní design pro zobrazení na mobilních telefonech. Redakční systém pro editaci údajů zákazníkem.<br>Webdesign- typizovaná šablona + dodatečná úprava některých prvků kódováním.</p>
        <img class="referenceIMG" src="fotky/nikdo.png">
        <p class="referenceTXT">„Nové stránky jsou krásné a nedají se srovnávat s těmi starými. Díky nim a dobrému dohledání na Seznamu jsem získala již po 14 dnech objednávku, která mi zaplatila podstatnou část investice do webu.“</p>
        </div>
</div>

.hook {
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

I thought that I can fix it  by using justify-content: space-between.
http://almaweby.cz/reference.html I need to use flexbox, but I would like to have it in columns.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that illustrates your problem rather than expecting us to root around in your source code.

Comment: Usually people use `flexbox` because they choose to, not because they need to. Why do you *need* to use it? Don't get me wrong, I'm all for it and highly recommend it, but your wording is a bit unusual. Please provide an example of your code, We can't inspect pictures, therefore can't tell what your code is missing unless we get a chance to look at it.

Comment: When external links die, questions become useless, so post a minimal code snippet instead and I will post an answer that fix it (found the issue already in the link)

Comment: @Shaggy I can´t make a sample code because I don´t know where I have mistake. If I make a brief part of my code then it works.

Comment: @LGSon I wanted to say you the same as to Shaggy

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I need to use it because without it whole positions and sense of my work is gone

Comment: So you chose to use it. Makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the `margin-right: 10px` and `width: 30%` that cause the second line to behave different, so change your `hook` rule to this

```
.hook {
    width: 33%;                  /*  changed from 30%  */
    /* margin-right: 10px;           removed           */
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```